# Python Google speech to text Conversion

Tags: python, google-api, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am using using spyder IDE for my speech to text conversion project using google Speech to text api. I have integrated google speech to text in my code and getting error something like "quota exhausted". upon going to dashboard in google console i am able see available quota.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()



sample_call = sr.AudioFile('sample_call_new.flac')
with sample_call as source:
    audio = r.record(source)

type(audio)

response = r.recognize_google_cloud(audio,language='en-US', show_all=True)
print(response)
```

- **ERROR**

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition__init__.py", line 932, in recognize_google_cloud
  raise RequestError(e)

RequestError: https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?alt=json returned "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'speech.googleapis.com/default_requests' and limit 'DefaultRequestsPerMinutePerProject' of service 'speech.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:764086051850'.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links': [{'description': 'Google developer console API key', 'url': 'https://console.developers.google.com/project/764086051850/apiui/credential'}]}]">*

Comment: The error seem related to your API limits.  Have you reviewed the rate limits for this service?  https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas

Answer (score 0):

You've exceeded your requests per minute:https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas

The limit is 900 requests per min.